# In a four mass six spring vibration, how is the kinetic energy represented

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, spring, coupled-oscillators

This is from Hobson, Riley, Bence Mathematical Methods, p 322. A spring system is described as follows (they are floating in air like molecules):

[image]

The equilibrium positions of four equal masses M of a square with sides 2L are $R_n=\pm L_i\pm L_j$ and displacements from equilibrium are $q_n=x_ni+y_nj$.
According to the text,

> "The coordinates for the system are thus x1, y1, x2, . . . , y4 and the kinetic energy of matrix A is given trivially by $MI_8$ where
>   $I_8$ is the 8x8 identity".

What does that mean? The velocity doesn't even appear. How does that relate to energy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An engineer would call it the "mass matrix" not the "kinetic energy matrix". The KE is given by $\frac 1 2 \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{v}$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is the vector of the velocity components $\dot x_1, \dots, \dot x_4, \dot y_1, \dots, \dot y_4$ and $\mathbf{M} = M \mathbf{I}_8$ - i.e. an $8\times8$ diagonal matrix with all the diagonal terms equal to $M$.

"Kinetic energy matrix" seems a silly name IMO, because as you said it *doesn't* fully represent the kinetic energy of the system.

The "stiffness matrix" (or whatever the mathematicians who wrote your book call it!) can similarly be written as an $8\times8$ matrix $\mathbf{K}$, though it's not so simple as the mass matrix. The potential energy stored in the springs is then given by $\frac 1 2 \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{K} \mathbf{x}$

Reading a textbook or web page on matrix methods for modelling multi-degree-of-freedom (MDOF) systems, written for engineers or physicists rather than for mathematicians, might help to understand the basic ideas.

Answer (score 7):

The origin of the mass matrix lies in a change of coordinates from Cartesian to generalized coordinates.

The kinetic energy of a system of $N$ particles in terms of Cartesian coordinates is
$$K=\frac 12\sum_{a=1}^Nm_a\dot{\vec r}_a\cdot\dot{\vec r}_a.$$
If the system is scleronomic, i.e., the relation between Cartesian and generalized coordinates do not involve time explicitly, $\vec r_i=\vec r_i(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$, then by the chain rule
$$K=\frac 12\sum_{a=1}^Nm_a\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial \vec r_a}{\partial q_i}\dot q_i\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial \vec r_a}{\partial q_j}\dot q_j.$$
By rearranging terms this can be written as
$$K=\frac12\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}\dot q_i\dot q_j=\frac 12\dot q^TA\dot q,$$
where  $A_{ij}\equiv \sum_am_a\frac{\partial \vec r_a}{\partial q_i}\cdot\frac{\partial\vec r_a}{\partial q_j}$ are the components of the mass matrix.

Sometimes it is safer calculate $A$ by using its definition. In simpler systems however it is better to write the kinetic energy explicitly in terms of the generalized coordinates and then compare with the quadratic form $\frac 12\dot q^TA\dot q$ to obtain $A$.